# How to send a custom validation Json object for the requestbody?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I send a custom JSON error instead of the one provided by spring? I need both custom validation and default validation like `@NotNull, @NotEmpty, @Email` and so on.

The function is only fired if the validation constraints in the `POJO` class level is not violated

### Code

```
package com.flasher.controller.rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.flasher.dto.UserRegistrationInfo;
import com.flasher.service.RegistrationService;
import com.flasher.validator.UserRegistrationInfoValidator;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class RegistrationControllerRest {

    @Autowired
    RegistrationService registrationService;

    @Autowired
    UserRegistrationInfoValidator userRegistrationInfoValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo, HttpServletRequest request,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        userRegistrationInfoValidator.setRemoteAddr(request.getRemoteAddr());
        userRegistrationInfoValidator.validate(userRegistrationInfo, bindingResult);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("has errors--");
            List<FieldError>   fieldErrors =bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
            fieldErrors.stream().forEach(fieldError->{
                System.out.println(fieldError.getField()+" "+fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            });
        }

    }

}


package com.flasher.dto;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class UserRegistrationInfo {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min = 4, max = 30)
    private String userName;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min = 4, max = 15)
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String reCaptcha;
    @NotNull
    private Boolean isAgreedTerms;

    public UserRegistrationInfo() {
    }

    public UserRegistrationInfo(String userName, String email, String password, String reCaptcha,
            Boolean isAgreedTerms) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.reCaptcha = reCaptcha;
        this.isAgreedTerms = isAgreedTerms;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getReCaptcha() {
        return reCaptcha;
    }

    public void setReCaptcha(String reCaptcha) {
        this.reCaptcha = reCaptcha;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAgreedTerms() {
        return isAgreedTerms;
    }

    public void setIsAgreedTerms(Boolean isAgreedTerms) {
        this.isAgreedTerms = isAgreedTerms;
    }

}



package com.flasher.validator;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.flasher.dto.UserRegistrationInfo;
import com.flasher.util.GoogleReCaptchaChecker;

public class UserRegistrationInfoValidator implements Validator {
    @Autowired
    GoogleReCaptchaChecker googleReCaptchaChecker;
    String remoteAddr;
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> className) {

        return UserRegistrationInfo.class.equals(className);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errs) {
        UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo = (UserRegistrationInfo) obj;

        if(Pattern.compile("[^\\w]").matcher(userRegistrationInfo.getUserName()).find()){
            errs.rejectValue("userName","", "Username cannot contain special characters");  
        }   
        if(Pattern.compile("[^(\\w!@#$%^&*())]").matcher(userRegistrationInfo.getUserName()).find()){
            errs.rejectValue("userName","", "Password cannot contain disallowed characters");   
        }
        if(!userRegistrationInfo.getIsAgreedTerms()){
            errs.rejectValue("isAgreedTerms", "you have to agree the terms and condition  in order to register");   
        }
        if(!googleReCaptchaChecker.validateGoogleReCaptcha(userRegistrationInfo.getReCaptcha(),remoteAddr)){
            errs.rejectValue("reCaptcha", "","invalid reCaptcha");  

        }

    }

    public void setRemoteAddr(String remoteAddr) {
        this.remoteAddr = remoteAddr;
    }

}
```

### Responce

```
{
  "timestamp": 1487250555542,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "Length.userRegistrationInfo.userName",
        "Length.userName",
        "Length.java.lang.String",
        "Length"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "userRegistrationInfo.userName",
            "userName"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "userName",
          "code": "userName"
        },
        30,
        4
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "length must be between 4 and 30",
      "objectName": "userRegistrationInfo",
      "field": "userName",
      "rejectedValue": "",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "Length"
    },
    {
      "codes": [
        "NotEmpty.userRegistrationInfo.userName",
        "NotEmpty.userName",
        "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
        "NotEmpty"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "userRegistrationInfo.userName",
            "userName"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "userName",
          "code": "userName"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "may not be empty",
      "objectName": "userRegistrationInfo",
      "field": "userName",
      "rejectedValue": "",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "NotEmpty"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='userRegistrationInfo'. Error count: 2",
  "path": "//api/v1/user"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorResponse handleMathodArgumentNotValidException(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException methodArgumentNotValidException) {

        BindingResult bindingResult = methodArgumentNotValidException.getBindingResult();
        List<ValidationError> validationErrors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
            fieldErrors.stream().forEach(fieldError -> {
                validationErrors.add(new ValidationError(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage()));
            });

        }
        return new ValidationErrorResponse(validationErrors);
    }
```

Comment: The Exception handler can be parameterized with MethodArgumentNotValidException and get the binding result from the exception object bcoz it is called before the API in case of MethodArgumentNotValidException

Answer (score 0):

Create pojo like this :

```
public class ValidationError {
    private String name;
    private String msg;*
```

and create another pojo :

```
public class ValidationErrorResponse {
    private  List<ValidationError> errors;
```

add this method :

```
 @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationErrorResponse handleValidationException(
            BindingResult exception) {
        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
        for (ObjectError er : exception.getAllErrors()) {
            FieldError fl = (FieldError) er;
            errors.add(new ValidationError(fl.getField(), er
                    .getDefaultMessage()));
        }
            return new ValidationErrorResponse(errors);

        }
```

and  change your method :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?>registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserRegistrationInfo userRegistrationInfo, HttpServletRequest request,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
   if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
                    return new ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorResponse>(
                    handleValidationException(br), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

      }
   // your bussines logic here

  return new  ResponseEntity .... 


}
```

Comment: The function is only fired if the validation constraints in the POJO class level is not violated, not working

Comment: finally, I got the solution. The Exception handler can be parameterized with MethodArgumentNotValidException and get the binding result from the exception object bcoz it is called before the API in case of MethodArgumentNotValidException.